# Highcharts scatter plot: alert coordinates on click event

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jquery-events, scatter-plot

I am using Highcharts' scatter plot and I'm trying to alert the coordinates (x,y) when someone clicks on a scatter plot's point.

You can see my options so far here: http://jsfiddle.net/athanott/ARf9M/

I only added

```
cursor: 'pointer',
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    alert('x: ' + event.xAxis[0].value);
                }
            }},
```

under plotOptions. If I delete the `event.xAxis[0].value` part in the alert command, the rest is printed normally, but it doesn't work as it is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.chartX` and `event.chartY` like so: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARf9M/1/)

Comment: That's excellent, thank you! Do you know if there's a way to display the values as they are displayed on mouse over? Something like alert("Height: " + [x] + "cm Weight: " + [y] + "kg"); ? Thank you.